# Code Coverage int .NET 5 Web API with Coverlet

Tags: code-coverage, .net-5, xunit, coverlet

I've web Api build it .NET 5.0.

**Web API structure:**

- Main Web Project (Contains controllers and other client specific data)
- Infrastructure Project (It has services and repositories with more business logic)
- Models (Db entities)
- Tests (Test cases written in Xunit)
- I have also added XUnit.Coverlet.Collector and XUnit.Coverlet.MSBuild projects too.

**The issue:**

- I'm not sure how to guide coverlet to use existing tests which are written in **Tests** project to the controller of main app.
- For now I have just created one controller in web api and their
  tests in both collector and msbuild project. this is working fine, I
  can generate code coverage for this controller i.e.
  **PrimeController.cs** (and then there are other classes and controllers with no coverage in reports.)
- **If I follow this working process, I've to copy all tests twice in both projects.**
- Isn't there any way I can just give a reference of my Tests project to msBuild and Collector?

[image])

Any help would be really appreciated.